# Qing Liu-Corollary 2.15

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, localization

In the book **Algebraic Geometry and Aritmetic Curves** of Qing Liu the author wants prove that if $\rho :A\longrightarrow B$ is flat (the $A$-algebra $B$ is flat), then for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ of $B$, $B_{\mathfrak{q}}$ is flat over $A_\mathfrak{p}$, where $\mathfrak{p}=\rho^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$. In order to do this he claim that $B_{\mathfrak{q}}$ is a localization of $B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}$. Can anyone explain this last fact?

Comment: That tensor product is the localization of B at the things of A which are not in p. If you further localize in the things which are not in q what happens?

Comment: Now...I obtain $B\otimes A_{\mathfrak{p}}\cong B_\mathfrak{p}$ but at this point i'm not able to proceed. Can you expande the answer?

Comment: You have an inclusion of multiplicative systems in $B$: $$\rho(A - \mathfrak p) \subset B - \mathfrak q$$. That is all you need to see that $B_{\mathfrak q}$ is a localization of the said tensor product.